# Just simple program but something goes wrong

Tags: c++

I have very simple piece of code. The goal is when i input four-digit number to check and verify that is divisible by 3.

```
     #include <iostream>
     using namespace std;
     int main()
{
     int number;
     cout<<"number: ";
     cin>>number;
     if(number%3==0)
     {
     cout<<"divisible by 3";
     }else{
       cout<<"not divisible by 3";
     }
}
```

And don't work.

I'm really really sorry. Seems the problem is in Dev++. I will delete this thread

Comment: "don't work" is not a question. Explain what the problem is, your observations.

Comment: "Don't work" is a useless report. If it worked, you wouldn't post on SO.

Comment: I've just built it and run it here, and it appears to work fine. So one of us is being a bit daft!

Comment: Doesn't calculate properly. Doesn't matter what number i input

Comment: @Goro: that's still not a proper report. If it is always giving you the same output, it must be working sometimes. If it is always giving you the opposite answer of what you expect, that's different. Please explain in more detail.

Comment: works fine on ideone.com. http://ideone.com/wiuzI

Comment: It works fine for me. Do you have a specific example of an input giving an incorrect output?

Comment: What IDE/compiler are you using?

Comment: I just tried with '1111' and the result was is 'divisible by 3'. Dev++. May be the problem is in my copiler.

Comment: You may have corrected your program when you copied it here. Please copy this program back to your machine, and try again.

Comment: Did you already debug your program?

Comment: on ideone i can see is working. also in VS working. I going to re-install Dev++. I'm sorry again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program is fine. End your output lines with `endl` to flush the output. If you still think it doesn't work, explain what you are doing, what the result is, and what you expect the result to be.

Comment: I think flushing the output is irrelevant. Adding a newline character could help readability, but that is independent of flushing.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I agree, but the OP did not specify what was broken, and it was the only issue I could see that I could consider "broken".

Comment: good point. OP seems unaware that the code isn't broken at all.

Answer (score 2):

Does the console window disappear immediately? It's a while since I did a C++ console application, but I remember that the behaviour in debug and release is refferent regarding whether the window closes after running or not.

There are better ways, but for quick checking I usually add an extra cin at the end to force the program not to exit.

Having no return value on `int main()` will cause a warning in most compilers, and it's best practice to have a return value of the type specified, but that won't be causing an error in this case

Comment: Yeah, but i add System("pause"); at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You must multiplied by the constituent digits of that number and then check if is divisible by 3.

edit: yes, here work fine also.

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting a

```
return 0;
```

just before you end your code as you are using an

```
int main()
```

or rather use a

```
void main()
```

and it ust work .:-)

Comment: The C++ standard actually allows you to omit the return statement for main, but does not allow you to declare main as void. An odd choice, I know, but that's how it is.

Comment: "Rather use `void main()`" is pretty flawed, as standard defines main as function returning `int` to the OS.

Comment: `main` implicitly returns 0 in `C++`. And `void main()` is not a standard compliant signature.

Answer (score -1):

I think you forget an library :
Maybe stdlib : #include

Comment: nope, cin and cout are in iostream